# (Julia 1.x) Getting type of #undef variable

Tags: julia

I am looking to get the types of the fields within a `struct` in order to set the field values correspondingly. Some data types initialise values on instantiation (e.g. `Int64`, `Float64`), whereas other types initialise to `#undef` (e.g. `String`, `Array`). Whilst `typeof(getfield())` works for the former types, it throws `UndefRefError` for the latter:

```
julia> mutable struct MyStruct
           a::Int64
           b::String
           MyStruct() = new()
       end

julia> foo = MyStruct()
MyStruct(0, #undef)

julia> typeof(getfield(foo, :a))
Int64

julia> typeof(getfield(foo, :b))
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Is there is way to get the type of an uninitialised variable or does `#undef` indicate the distinct lack of a type? Alternatively, is it possible to initialise default values using the inner constructor? e.g.

```
julia> mutable struct MyStruct
           a::Int64
           b::String
           MyStruct() = new(b = "")
       end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `fieldtype` function:

```
julia> fieldtype(MyStruct, :a)
Int64                         

julia> fieldtype(MyStruct, :b)
String
```

To your other question, you surely can initialize fields.

```
mutable struct MyStruct
    a::Int64
    b::String
    MyStruct() = new(0,"") # will initialize a as 0 and b as ""
end
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! Also thank you for answering the second part - I had thought it would be possible, but at least now I know for future.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow-on, you can get a tuple of all field types with [`fieldtypes`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/index.html#Base.fieldtypes):

```
julia> fieldtypes(MyStruct)
(Int64, String)
```